# await is not defined [discord js]

Tags: javascript, discord

```
let msg = await;
message.channel.sendMessage('Searching... :mag_right:');
let item = args[1];
if(item == 'hi'){
    msg.edit(":newspaper: Hi : Test search item")
    return;
}
```

I'm trying to use await to define "msg" as the message (Searching... :mag_right:) But it doesn't seem to be working and returns with
(x is me censoring out personal information )

```
ReferenceError: await is not defined
    at Client.bot.on.message (C:\Users\x\Desktop\Tantalite wikibot\index.js:41:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Client.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\x\Desktop\Tantalite wikibot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\x\Desktop\Tantalite wikibot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:120:65)
    at WebSocketManager.eventMessage (C:\Users\x\Desktop\Tantalite wikibot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:273:31)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\x\Desktop\Tantalite wikibot\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:442:14)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at Receiver.ontext (C:\Users\x\Desktop\Tantalite wikibot\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:841:10)
```

Comment: Oh also it only makes sense when used inside an `async` function.

Comment: Sorry, but how would I do that?

Comment: [Familiarize yourself with the basics of `async` functions and `await`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Comment: @Pointy I wouldn't say 'must be followed'. It probably makes the only sense when it's followed by a promise (eval to promise). But in general, I just tried, it doesn't throw any error if it's not followed. E.g. `await 4;`. What I'm confused with is that I'm getting an error 'await is not defined' and cannot figure out why. That's how I found this question

Comment: Even if I just use `let a = await;` as the OP, it throws 'unexpected token ;', not 'is not defined'.

Comment: I figured it out. It's because await is a legitimate identifier. And if it occurs in an async funciton, it acts as an operator. Otherwise, if it's a normal function, it's an identifier

Comment: @DmitryKoroliov yes, you are correct, and my comment is not correct. (Note that it's a fairly old comment, in my weak defense.)